# CILightTunnel and CIKaleidoscope Filters

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I'm able to create a CIGausianBlur filter using a local image.  Now, I'm attempting to create a CIKaleidoscope filter and CILightTunnel using the same format.  My code for the Kaleidoscope filter is:

```
- (UIImage *)applyKaleidoscopeToImage:(UIImage *)image {

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *ci_image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIKaleidoscope"];
    [filter setValue:ci_image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:@55 forKey:kCIInputAngleKey];
    CIVector *civ = [CIVector vectorWithX:50 Y:50];
    [filter setValue:civ forKey:kCIInputCenterKey];
    CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
}
```

For this method, I'm getting an uncaught exception of type NSException and warning of trying to replace an array objet with a nil value.

My code for the CILightFilter is as follows:

```
- (UIImage *)applyLightTunnelToImage:(UIImage *)image {

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *ci_image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILightTunnel"];
    [filter setValue:ci_image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    CIVector *civ = [CIVector vectorWithX:50 Y:50];
    [filter setValue:civ forKey:kCIInputCenterKey];

    [filter setValue:@5 forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];

    //[filter setValue:@45 forKey:kCIInputAngleKey];

    CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation];
}
```

I get the same nil result here as well.  Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You'll have an easier time fixing this error if you can pinpoint where it occurs. Try setting [an exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) in Xcode. If you still can't fix your problem once you've found the line that crashes, update your question with that information and you'll be more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: The CIImage, result is nil.  Thus, CoreImage is not sending back any data.

Answer (score 0):

Since both are destructive filters the rect parameter `[result extent]` gonna be always some pointless figures. 
Use original rect or rect you wish to see and it gonna most probably work correctly.